# Cordova firebase plugin onTokenRefresh when app is closed

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I made a simple Ionic app with Firebase Cloud Messaging and Cordova firebase plugin. When the app is fired i get the device token and save it to database. The problem appears when the user clears the app data and the token is deleted. For this i subscribed to onTokenRefresh() but it's not fired when the app is closed. So the users won't receive any notifications because in my database there is still the old token until he opens the app again and registers the new token.

How can i intercept this event even if the app is closed? Is this possible using Ionic and Cordova, or it has to be native app?

there is another question same scenario on Github but no answers -> https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1002